# elevation factor when calculating Distance

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

i am working on android GPS based application in which i have to calculate the distance between two  points which are located on trails  i currently use  `Location.distanceTo` method for calculating distance my question is is `Location.distanceTo` function consider an elevation factor ? if not then what is the best way to calculate distance on trails ? or is there any api available for this purpose ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be next to impossible to really do it.  distanceTo returns the flight distance-  the distance as if you were flying at ground level and had nothing blocking you.  You could factor elevation into that, but it would be fairly useless-  knowing you're 100m below a given point is a bit pointless because its never 100m to get to that point-  you're never going purely vertical.  If the slope is 10%, you're going at least 1000m to rise the 100m.

For the same reason, distanceTo isn't the best for anything in the outdoors.  Trails twist and turn.  distanceTo gives the direct distance.  It will always underestimate.  If you want an accurate actual distance you need to use a routing API like google maps that knows the length of every piece of road.